# How To to Identify/Map Glossary Terms in PDFs

Tags: excel, pdf, automation

Hello you beautiful people,

I'm hoping one of you can save me hours and hours of work by giving me a genius solution to automate this task...

I have 200 PDFs in a document on my Mac. The file name of each PDF is a unique 8 letter code.

I also have an Excel Glossary where common terms used in those PDFs are defined - there are around 1500 glossary terms.

My boss wants that we create an additional column in the excel called "Documents Where Term is Used" and list all of the documents using that term.

We will then transfer this into a database to manage the upkeep of this mapping going forward. My need here is the initial mapping

Instead of manually opening each PDF which is just not do-able. how can i have some sort of script take the term in each row of the Excel, scan the 200 documents to see if that term is used, and populate the column in the Excel with the file names of the PDFs where that term is actually used.

As you can imagine, 1500 terms times 200 PDFs = i will die before i finish this if i try to do this manually

All ideas and solutions welcome. I can also do this on a Windows machine if need be

Thanks all, realllllly excited to hear your solutions

[example spreadsheet setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lowm7.png)
[example folder with files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2zQ5i.png)

Answer (score 0):

it would help to know a bit more about your pdf files - is that plain text, tables, a mix...? Have you already tried to import them into Excel, which may make things easier?

If the content to look up is in Excel (for example one document by tab), you can make a relatively simple VBA code that would look up each term in cell *Ax* in each document (i.e. in each tab), and add the name of the document/tab to the corresponding *Cx* cell. There would be 1 loop for each tab nested into a loop for each term (or the other way around).

Happy to give more support when you say a bit more about your pdf and/or your initial attempt on this

I hope that helps!